# Delphi XE6 - Access Violation at address 5006677D in module 'trl200.bpl'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I just upgraded to Delphi XE6. Everything went fine.

I installed a custom .bpl file and now when I try to load Delphi XE6 i get an error.

```
Access Violation at address 5006677D in module 'trl200.bpl'
```

I suspect it is because I forgot to recompile my component package before installing it on XE6.

Does anyone know where I can look to tell XE6 not to try to load this?

Comment: Just delete bpl file you installed. I think it is simplest way.

Comment: AG's idea is probably the simplest one.  Otherwise, have you tried looking for it in the registry (HKCU) under your Delphi version, under the key "Known IDE packages"?

Comment: Are you sure the file is "trl200" and not "rtl200"? "rtl200.bpl" is one of the Delphi runtime libraries, and deleting it will totally break your Delphi installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the bpl you tried to install (or rename it as suggested below). After a restart of Delphi you will be asked if you want to load the bpl next time Delphi is started, just press "no". Now try to install the bpl again, but then compiled for XE6. Do not delete rtl200.bpl! I have done so many times and never had to change the registry.

Comment: Note this also causes problems when you fix the issue and want the DLL loaded. Telling the IDE not to load next time adds it to a list of disabled packages in the registry, and manually editing the registry is the only way to remove it from that list. Also, it's usually a better idea to suggest **renaming** it rather than **deleting** it.